# How can I connect to another SQL database in phpMyAdmin?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

I was given credentials for a SQL database and would like to connect to it then edit in phpMyAdmin. Although, I have no clue how to connect to another database from my computer.

Url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/intelyc,
Username: root,
Password: Not Saying

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the PHPMyAdmin and you have it installed on your local computer - you can change connection host in the PHPMyAdmin's configuration.

But my advice to you, just download DB management application like Navicat for example - it is a more comfortable way for work with DB.

Comment: I'll go ahead and try Navicat. If it works, I'll accept your answer. Thanks!

Comment: I installed Navicat for mySQL. When I press create new connection, and select mySQL I put in the credentials. Host Name/IP Address: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/intelyc, Port: 3306, User Name: root, Password: [Classified]. Although, I can't connect. Why is that?

Comment: I would guess @mccrafter1212 that Navicat does not use JDBC credentials. Try a host of `localhost` instead, and if it lets you put in a database name, use `intelyc`.

Comment: Host name: `localhost`, Username: `root`, password: `***`. After connection select table `intelyc`